# Корректная работа вложенных фрагментов с элементами меню ActionBar?

Tags: android-fragment, actionbar, android

Здраствуйте. Помогите найти решение.

Что есть:
Android 4.2.2 (и устройство, и эмулятор).

Задача:
Фрагмент (со списком в ActionBar) -> нажимаем на элемент списка -> запускам вложенный фрагмент, который должен добавить свои иконки в меню ActionBar, при этом список, который создал родительский фрагмент, должен остаться.

Проблема:  
Родительский фрагмент содержит контейнер для вложенных фрагментов, а также родительский фрагмент пересоздает Action Bar и добавляет в него список (меню навигации), при нажатии на элемент которого отображается нужный вложенный фрагмент, который, в свою очередь, должен добавить в ActionBar свои элементы меню. Однако **при делегировании вложенному фрагменту возможности управлять элементами меню (setHasOptionsMenu(true))** приложение начинает бесконечно пересоздавать этот самый вложенный фрагмент и подвисает. Если отключить делегирование, то вложенные фрагменты работают нормально, но не создают свои элементы меню.

Вот что выдает **LogCat**: Choreographer: Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Мой код:

**Родительский фрагмент:**

```
public class FragmentBugs extends Fragment  implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bugs_empty, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

         restoreActionBar();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bugs, menu);
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void restoreActionBar(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.removeAllTabs();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bug);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.title_section5);

        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.action_list_bugs, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        switch(itemPosition){
        case 0:
                //Если  вложенному фрагменту, я разрешу управление меню,
               // то этот пункт будет выполняться бесконечно,  пока приложение
              // не зависнет
        Log.d("MyLog", "Fr1");
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.containerBugs, new BugsNewEventFragment(),"Fr1")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

            break;

        case 1:
        Log.d("MyLog", "Fr2");
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.containerBugs, new BugsEventHistoryFragment(),"Fr2")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Вложенный фрагмент:**

```
public class BugsNewEventFragment  extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);//Если  поставить   false,  то этот вложенный фрагмент не добавит свои элементы меню,  но будет нормально работать

    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bugs_new_event, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bugs_new, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать во вложенных фрагментах создать интерфейс и реализовать методы для обновления меню по событию во фрагменте в родительском фрагменте. Я так делаю, когда мне нужна обратная связь между фрагментами и активити, например.